# autosubmit selectbox without button

Tags: php, javascript, submit

I want to submit selectbox automatically without submit, also for each value i want to POST them on same page of php, tried below code but not able to retrive values of POST.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo $_POST['modelS'];}?>

<form action="cal1.php" method="post"> 
<select name="modelS" onchange="this.form.elements['submit'].click();">
     <option value="A" selected>Show All</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name=post VALUE=$_POST['modelS']>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="search" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: trigger script on Onchange event

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="modelS" onchange="document.form.submit();">
```